# Xen 4.0.1 on ubuntu 10.10 server edition

Tags: ubuntu, xen

i have a problem to booting xen kernel. At system start i obtain the next message:

gave up waiting for root device. common problems:

```
   boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   check root= (did the system wait for the righ device?)
   missing modules (cat /proc/modules: ls /dev)
```

You have some idea to fix this problem?

Many thanks.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Check grub config:

```
menuentry "Xen 4.0.1  2.6.xx.xx" {
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root=(hd0,msdos1)
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set ID
  multiboot /boot/xen.gz
  module /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.xx.xx root=/dev/sda1
  module /boot/initrd-2.6.xx.xx.img
}
```

ID copy from other menuentry in /boot/grub/grub.cfg.